# Open a local file (ex: pdf,txt,docx) in Angular2 in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I wonder if it is possible to open a file for example a '.pdf' directly in the `<a>` tag.

example in:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:///rootmap/filetoshow.pdf"></a>
```

Code above will result in open a pdf in a new tab.

- If not this is possible what is the best way to handle this, without go via an service.

Comment: How would you do that without Angular2? What kind of service are you talking about?

Comment: I mean access a local file and link it for example i have a pdf in root directory, but Angular2 overrides how you can access files?

Comment: Angular2 doesn't do anything about files.

Comment: Works now, was something else. Thanks was thinking it was how Angular2 handle stuff.

Comment: Did you solve it?
What do you get when you do:
<a target="_blank" [href]="'file:///rootmap/filetoshow.pdf'"></a>
(I added [] and '')

Comment: I solved it with my code above, the file i was trying to open was not copied right.